# CIDR address calculation (network and broadcast address)

Tags: cidr

I'm a little stuck with something right now:

Trying to figure out how to calculate the network/broadcast address for the following CIDR IP: 10.20.30.45/13.

As far as I can see, the fact that the network part of this IP is 13 bits big, tells us that the address hast got to be changed beginning with the seccond oktett when determining the network address
    -> 10.X.0.0

But what will X be, and how can I calculate X?

Comment: When you are using CIDR notation with lengths that are not a multiple of 8, you need to just ignore the "octets". Rewrite the address as a 32-bit number (0x0a141e2d), and take the top 13 bits as your network address, then convert it back to octet notation to get 10.16.0.0 for your network, or 10.23.255.255 for your broadcast. Many Linux distros come with a script named `ipcalc` to handle such tasks for you...

Answer (score 2):

You can convert 10.20.30.45 to binary and /13 to binary, which is 255.248.0.0.

**10.20.30.45** in binary would be 00001010 00010100 00011110 00101101
**255.248.0.0** is 11111111 11111000 00000000 00000000

Then compare them:

```
00001010 00010100 00011110 00101101
11111111 11111000 00000000 00000000
______________________________________
00001010 00010000 00000000 00000000 => back to decimal is 10.16.0.0
```

To get the broadcast address you have to do a binary inversion of the CIDR or Netmask Address.

Or you can you this [CIDR converter](http://ipconvertertools.com/cidr2ipranges) to automate it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In C(++):

```
#ifdef __FreeBSD__
#include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  in_addr net, broadcast;
  int bits = inet_net_pton(AF_INET, "10.20.30.45/13", &net, sizeof(net));
  assert((bits != -1));  // assert that inet_net_pton understood us
  // Apply CIDR mask to address to get the network
  if (bits > 0) {  // u32 << 32 is undefined
    uint32_t mask = htonl((0xFFFFFFFFu) << (32 - bits));
    net.s_addr &= mask;
  }
  broadcast = net;
  // Do the same for broadcast
  if (bits < 32) {
    uint32_t mask = htonl((0xFFFFFFFFu) >> bits);
    broadcast.s_addr |= mask;
  }
  std::cout << "Network: " << inet_ntoa(net) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Broadcast: " << inet_ntoa(broadcast) << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Network: 10.16.0.0
Broadcast: 10.23.255.255
```